# Insert new rows in pandas dataframe, altering some timestamps while keeping other data

Tags: python, pandas

```
1     2016-10-01 01:00:00       1014.7           23.6
2     2016-10-01 02:00:00       1014.3           23.6
3     2016-10-01 03:00:00       1014.3           23.8
4     2016-10-01 04:00:00       1014.3           23.8
5     2016-10-01 05:00:00       1014.4           24.3
6     2016-10-01 06:00:00       1014.9           24.6
7     2016-10-01 07:00:00       1015.6           25.7
8     2016-10-01 08:00:00       1015.8             26
9     2016-10-01 09:00:00       1016.3           27.3
10    2016-10-01 10:00:00       1016.5           25.8
11    2016-10-01 11:00:00       1016.6             26
12    2016-10-01 12:00:00       1016.6           27.3
```

I have a dataframe as shown above with a timestamp column and some pressure columns. The problem is that the timestamps are hourly and i need a 10 minutes interval timeseries. I would therefore like to insert 5 new rows after each row where i add 10 minutes to the previous timestamp and just keep the pressure data. Can anyone help me with this, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ffill.html):

```
print (df)
                   date       a     b
1   2016-10-01 01:00:00  1014.7  23.6
2   2016-10-01 02:00:00  1014.3  23.6
3   2016-10-01 03:00:00  1014.3  23.8
4   2016-10-01 04:00:00  1014.3  23.8
5   2016-10-01 05:00:00  1014.4  24.3
6   2016-10-01 06:00:00  1014.9  24.6
7   2016-10-01 07:00:00  1015.6  25.7
8   2016-10-01 08:00:00  1015.8  26.0
9   2016-10-01 09:00:00  1016.3  27.3
10  2016-10-01 10:00:00  1016.5  25.8
11  2016-10-01 11:00:00  1016.6  26.0
12  2016-10-01 12:00:00  1016.6  27.3
```

---

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.set_index('date').resample('10T').ffill()
print (df.head(10))
                          a     b
date                             
2016-10-01 01:00:00  1014.7  23.6
2016-10-01 01:10:00  1014.7  23.6
2016-10-01 01:20:00  1014.7  23.6
2016-10-01 01:30:00  1014.7  23.6
2016-10-01 01:40:00  1014.7  23.6
2016-10-01 01:50:00  1014.7  23.6
2016-10-01 02:00:00  1014.3  23.6
2016-10-01 02:10:00  1014.3  23.6
2016-10-01 02:20:00  1014.3  23.6
2016-10-01 02:30:00  1014.3  23.6
```

Comment: @liliscent - Thank you.

Comment: Hmm it seems exactly like what i need, i though get an error "No numeric types to aggregate" but i think that maybe has something to do with my pandas version perhaps.

Comment: @NicklasKoldkjær - No, there is problem `print (df.dtypes)` - columns `a` and `b` are niot numeric, but `object`, what is obviously strings. So need `df = df.set_index('date').astype(float).resample('10T').ffill()` for converting first.

Comment: Ahh yeah that makes sense, thank you very much worked like a charm :)